# Execute pyspark job in driver node

Tags: pyspark, hadoop-yarn

I have a 3 node cluster and working in client mode.
Spark version is 3.0 Yarn as resource manager

I want my spark application to run on application master JVM. That is in uber mode.

How can i achieve this in Client mode.

I tried with setting
Spark.conf("spark.uber.enable","true")
After executing application. I see that the application is executed on the worker node and not the driver node.